# SCSS the best way to overwrite from CSS

Tags: sass, refactoring

Can you help me improve the following to SCSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
    color: $mainhover-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make much sense.

Anyway - it is already valid SCSS - but invalid CSS as it requires compilation.

There are plenty of online CSS to SCSS converters. But none of them will work unless you change `$mainhover-color` to its compiled value.

This is what it would be post-refactoring:

```
.navbar-default {
    .navbar-brand {
        &:hover,
        &:focus,
        &:active,
        &.active {
            color: $mainhover-color;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a very useful question on SO. You should read up on SCSS basics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to change that to SCSS as CSS is valid in SASS/SCSS and that all you would add is nesting, but provided you still want to do it, you could go this way :

```
.navbar-default {
    .navbar-brand {
        &:hover,
        &:active,
        &:focus,
        &.active {
            color: $mainhover-color;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't make it better, it's just another syntax. I advise you read more on SCSS basics.